# Groovy String and datestamp

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy and wonder following is possible?

I have a file generated automatically with datestamp, example saledata20180429
Is it possible to code this with Groovy and convert the filename to saledata-2018-04-29.txt

Comment: Is the original file name expected to always have the same format and length? (i.e., no date parsing required)?

Comment: yes, the file has same format and length...only the date is changed everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Simple substring calls can get that done:

```
def name = 'saledata20180429'
def newname = "saledata-${name[8..11]}-${name[12..13]}-${name[14..15]}.txt"
```

`newname` evaluates to `'saledata-2018-04-29.txt'`

Comment: Thank so much, it works! Just curious, how can I get it work if my sale data file name is different every day?
'saledata20180429'
'saledata20180430
'saledata20180501''

Comment: @KaLi That should be fine. All you need to change is the input in the variable `name`. the result is calculated based on the structure of the input, so it should always work as long as the input file name has the same structure/length...

Comment: You should be able to run this anywhere valid groovy can be run